# TextBlock wrapping on Grid (UWP)

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp

Have been making a bit of research on this but haven't been able to solve it:

I have a `GridView`, here is all the code for it:

```
<GridView Name="NewsGrid" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="NewsGrid_ItemClick">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:News">
                <Grid Height="Auto" Margin="0" Width="440">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="{x:Bind Image}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        Stretch="UniformToFill"
                        Margin="5"
                        Height="247"
                        Width="440"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Body}"
                           Foreground="SteelBlue"
                           Grid.Row="1"
                           Height="Auto"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                           Width="440"
                           Margin="5 0 5 0"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is for the `TextBlock` to wrap if the length of the text goes over 440 pixels. The code above does not accomplish that. To give you some visuals, here is the result from the code above:

[image]

So that last word is "Pass" and ask you can see it just keeps going. I just want it to break into a new line underneath. How can I achieve this? I have also tried to swap my `Grid` for a `StackPanel` but the result is the same.

**Update 1**
Added `TextWrapping="Wrap"` to my `TextBlock`, visual result is this:

[image]

The last word doesn't show up anymore, not even in the same line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `TextWrapping="Wrap"` to your `TextBlock`.

Also!
For the definitions of rows this has to happen:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Comment: you can see that "Pass" does not show anymore on the line which means the wrapping worked. The problem is you don't have enough vertical space on your TextBlock.

Comment: Right, but doesn't `Height="Auto"` solve that? Is the parent `Grid` the issue? Because I also have `Height="Auto"` for the parent `Grid`.

Comment: You have `<RowDefinition Height="*"/>`. Try setting that to Auto instead. `Height=Auto` on TextBlock is redundant.

Comment: I got it! I had to swap the `Heights` on `RowDefinitions` out

Comment: Updated the answer with that